# How to Add Dotted Underlining Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML file that has a modified style so that the underline tag results in a dotted line.

```
<style type="text/css">
  u {    
     border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
     text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>
```

I want a function that will find elements by class and apply this underline style. It needs to be in a JS function because the underlining only occurs during certain events (mouseover and onclick). What would my javascript code look like?

So far I have:

```
    function underline(id){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].style.?????}
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
element.style.borderBottom = '2px dotted black';
```

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/B1KMusic/2mYFK/)

If you want to have the width of the "underline" match the width of the text, you can add this:

```
element.style.display = 'inline';
```

Comment: So I wouldn't even need a style change in my header with this?

Comment: @jcoat No you would not. The javascript method for making an "underline" would be to use `element.style.borderBottom`, this creates a border on the bottom, achieving the effect you wanted. You can additionally set `element.style.display` to `"inline"` and have the width of the underline match the element's text. I've also updated the example to show it works with multiple elements :)

Answer (score 1):

Why does it need to be done via javascript?  You can just use the [css class selector](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssintermediate/classid/):

```
.myClass
{
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I only want the class underlined on certain events

Comment: @jcoat You can add the class to your particular elements during those events. It's still better to separate the styling from JavaScript and keep it in the CSS file.

Comment: As @sweetamylase said, just [add/remove](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript) the classes during the event.

Answer (score 1):

Fyi, the `<u>` tag is non-semantic.
Also, your css selector would be more useful if you use class for applying the styles:

```
.underline{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So your html could be:

```
<p>Blah blah <span class="underline">underline this</span> blah blah.</p>
```